# Accessing Vagrant box from external network

Tags: vagrant, vpn

Before posting this, I've done some research and tried different solutions. The question is how to configure a system so that it would be possible to SSH into it's vagrant box from external/different network?

I have a Windows machine at home. I have installed Vagrant and now able to access the contents both via HTTP and SSH from any device connected to very same network.

What I want to do is to be able to get a laptop, go to a nice little café just across the river, sit down and work on my project which sits in that Vagrant box on my home desktop PC.

I am quite terrible in networking and not sure what is the solution. Do I need to make my home desktop a server? If so, which steps should I take? Do I need to do configure something in my router software? Or do I need to create some kind of VPN stuff where Vagrant thinks I am actually requesting it's contents from the same home network or perhaps I just better give up and setup a droplet in the DigitalOcean instead?

To moderators: please don't shut this question because the answer is an opinion based. I am happy to listen to these opinions and I want to know which steps to follow to achieve what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just copy your Vagrantfile to the laptop and spin up an instance there? It would be much less work, faster, and importantly much safer than opening up your desktop computer to the world.

I think your own suggestion of a remote server is also a valid option, although not quite as simple as just using the laptop.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The answer is: because I will have to sync it back with my desktop machine later on and I don't want it

Comment: Do you need a GUI? or just CLI access? If just CLI, you could enable SSH on your desktop, SSH in front the laptop and then boot & connect to the Vagrant box from the SSH session.

Comment: It is SSH and HTTP. I will google on how to enable SSH on my desktop now